# Passing functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

With reference to the code from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html)

With reference to the `addListener(instance:Object, eventName:string, handler:Function)` function. Here we pass in a handler. So `toggleBounce` is called when you click it.

I could also change it to `var toggleFn = function toggleBounce() {....)` and pass in `toggleFn`

My question is, can I pass in a function which takes parameters, for example if I wanted the handler to be a `zoom(mapOptions.zoom -5)` or similar function.

I know this is essentially a 'how do you pass functions as parameters' question but I just can't get it to work with different combinations.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {zoom: 13, center: stockholm };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: parliament });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) { marker.setAnimation(null);} 
  else {marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a anonymous function:

```
functionToPassTo(function(){ zoom(mapOptions.zoom -5) });
```

You can also pass variables:

```
var options = "something";
functionToPassTo(function(){ zoom(options) });
```

The only other way would be to store the function in a variable:

```
var options = "something",
func=function(){ zoom(options) });
functionToPassTo(func);
```

Comment: Cheers. Is this the only way to do it? Can I not pass in a reference?

Comment: @Tim you can pass a function reference, but that just gets you to the function itself and doesn't handle your parameters. What you want is a reference to a function that calls the function you *really* want to call, passing the parameters too.

Comment: Ok but say I wanted to pass in a local variable, such as the `mapOptions` as one of the parameters? The `toggleBounce()` method still can't access it

Comment: @JCOC611 thank you for that. I can get what I want to do using anonymous functions now. However, I'd still like to know if its possible any other way. I personally hate the mess of anonymous functions bring to code but if its the only way to do this so be it.

Comment: @Tim: Edited again, you can store the new function in a variable...although that really is just wasting more code...

Comment: @JCOC611. Apologies for taking so long to mark this as at the correct answer. Enjoy the bounty!

Comment: @Tim: no problem, thanks! *Goes and buys an ice cream with the points*